# Instantiating prefabs in a random location picked from a specified set of locations in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, prefab

[Prefabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whZlb.png)
[Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKKmh.png)
HI, I was wondering, how could I instantiate one prefab (from an array/list) under one of the random red squares! Please help me

Comment: Don't expect other people to write your code for you.  Please review this page on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

just copy this:

```
// move this 3 lines to top of your class
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using Unity.Mathematics;

// put this inside your class
public List<GameObject> prefabsList = new List<GameObject>();
public List<Transform> redSquaresList = new List<Transform>();

private void Start()
{
    var randomPrefab = Random.Range(0, prefabsList.Count);
    var randomSquare = Random.Range(0, redSquaresList.Count);
    Instantiate(prefabsList[randomPrefab], redSquaresList[randomSquare].position, quaternion.identity);
}
```

and then fill those lists in editor as you want